# Different checkout form based on different membership

Tags: views, commerce, ubercart

I have four types of membership.

1) non school Organizational Membership.

2) Individual Membership.

3) School Membership

4) Free Membership.

So based on these membership i want to open different checkout form.

Currently i used ubercart module and it open the same checkout page for all members.

Here are some attached screenshot, so i want the same functionality like attached screenshot.

1) membership page.
[image]
2) Join us page:-

[image]

3) Checkout page (four kind of checkout form based on membership).

a) non school Organizational Membership checkout page:-

[image]

b) Individual Membership checkout page:-

[image]

c) school Membership checkout page:-

[image]

d) Free Membership checkout page:-

[image]

Can anybody tell me what kind of module i need to use to achieve this kind of functionality, or if i need to do customization then please provide me some idea about that.

Thanks.